# how to add many resources in folder app_localresources?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, local

In Visual Studio, I have the folder *app_localresource*s with 2 resources: example.aspx.resx and example.aspx.en.resx. example.aspx.resx file was created automatically and the another is a copy, but in the solution I have: example.aspx, example2.aspx, example3.aspx... How do I add more resources files automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution, just it's to be in design mode and next click in the menu tools-> generate local resource.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "automatically"? It seems that you could use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418542(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article. Code excerpt taken from this article:

```
using (ResXResourceWriter resx = new ResXResourceWriter(@".\CarResources.resx"))
  {
     resx.AddResource("Title", "Classic American Cars");
     resx.AddResource("HeaderString1", "Make");
     resx.AddResource("HeaderString2", "Model");
     resx.AddResource("HeaderString3", "Year");
     resx.AddResource("HeaderString4", "Doors");
     resx.AddResource("HeaderString5", "Cylinders");
     resx.AddResource("Information", SystemIcons.Information);   
  }
```